# How do I close another form with a checkbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 forms MainUI and Log

I want to close Log from MainUI with a checkBox but I can't figure out how to do that.

This is my code in MainUI :

```
public void checkBox4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
        if (checkBox4.Checked == true)
        {
            Log F2 = new Log();
            F2.Show();
        }
        else if (checkBox4.Checked == false)
        {
            //Here should the exit code be for the Log form.
        }
}
```

Log:

```
public partial class Log : Form
{       
    public Log()
    {         
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Log_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    public void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

}
```

Comment: Declare F2 somewhere such the scope and lifetime will let you access it when you call checkBox4_CheckedChanged the second time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the variable visible at method level for that. move it outside the if block for that:

```
public class MainUIForm : Form
{
  private Log F2  = null;

  public void checkBox4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {      

      if (checkBox4.Checked)
      {
        F2 = new Log();
        F2.Show();
      }
      else
      {
        F2?.Close(); // for closing which will dispose it
      }
   }
}
```

This assumes that when you check the checkbox, you need a new fresh window to be opened for `Log` and discard previous window and it's state.

If the Log window needs to be created/instantiated once and you just need to show it to user and hide depending on the checkbox either checked or not, then you would need to adjust the code like:

```
public class MainUIForm : Form
{
  private Log F2 = new Log();

  public void checkBox4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {      

      checkBox4.Checked ?
        F2.Show() :
        F2.Hide();

   }
}
```

Comment: yes i agree, i have just shown with comments that it could be hidden or close as needed and explained in last line about it

Comment: I deleted my old comments to clean up this post.

Comment: @Nerreg i have updated the post, please try the latest code.

Comment: Everything works as it should right now : ) the post was solved. But I still don't know how to change properties on another form (anotherpost)

Answer (score 1):

Modify Your Main form should like this

```
///Make it as global
Log F2 = null;

public void checkBox4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {      

        if (checkBox4.Checked == true)
        {   
            if(F2 == null)
                {
                  F2=new Log();
                }
            F2.Show();
        }
        else if (checkBox4.Checked == false && F2 != null)
        { 
            F2.Hide();
            F2.Close();
            //Here should the exit code be for the Log form.
        }
}
```

Comment: This won't close the form,  F2=new Log(); would need to be inside the first `if`

Answer (score -1):

The post was solved, I did Log.Close(); instead of Log.Hide() FIXED!

Comment: That doesn't make sense given the code you posted. Please give us a complete update.